# Проблема с запуском wkhtmltopdf из python

Tags: python

Я новичок в пайтоне, но облазив множество ссылок, решения данной проблемы я не нашел.

```
    C:\Users\Aero>pip install wkhtmltopdf
Collecting wkhtmltopdf
  Using cached wkhtmltopdf-0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: wkhtmltopdf
  Running setup.py install for wkhtmltopdf
Successfully installed wkhtmltopdf-0.2

C:\Users\Aero>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wkhtmltopdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import WKhtmlToPdf, wkhtmltopdf
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

Буду благодарен любым идеям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот модуль только под Python 2. Придётся или дожидаться портирования, или портировать самостоятельно, или использовать второй питон, или воспользоваться другой библиотекой (гугл сообщает мне про [wkhtmltopdf-wrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf-wrapper))

Comment: Да, я после попытки запустить ``main.py`` увидел, что там ``print`` идет как оператор, а не функция, что недоступно в питоне 3, это толкнуло меня установить второй, и там заработало :)

Comment: @Aero: Если речь о [python-wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/qoda/python-wkhtmltopdf), то не должно на Винде работать.